# KVO: +keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key> doesn't work with (subclass of) NSObjectController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, nsobjectcontroller

I have a KVO-able class (call it `Observee`), which `affectedValue` dynamic property is affected by `affectingValue` property. The dependency between the properties is defined by implementing `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue` method.

Setting a value to `affectingValue` notifies that `affectedValue`  has changed as I expected,  **unless** `Ovservee` is a subclass of `NSObjectController`. Full example follows:

```
@interface Observee : NSObject // or NSObjectController
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) id affectedValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id affectingValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArrayController *arrayController;
@end

@implementation Observee

@dynamic affectedValue;
- (id)affectedValue { return nil; }

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue {
  NSLog(@"keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue called");
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"affectingValue"];
}

@end

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) Observee *observee;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
  self.observee = [[Observee alloc] init];
  [self.observee addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:@"affectedValue"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:NULL];
  NSLog(@"setting value to affectingValue");
  self.observee.affectingValue = @42;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  NSLog(@"affected key path = %@", keyPath);
}

@end
```

The example works fine and outputs as the following when `Observee` derives `NSObject`:

```
keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue called
setting value to affectingValue
affected key path = affectedValue
```

but when `Observee` derives `NSObjectController`:

```
keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue called
setting value to affectingValue
```

(note that "affected key path = affectedValue" is absent.)

It seems that `keyPathsForValuesAffectingAffectedValue` is called in both cases but it is no-op in the latter.

Also, any key paths involving an instance of (subclass of) `NSObjectController` won't affect other key paths, such as:

```
@implementation SomeObject

// `someValue` won't be affected by `key.path.(snip).arrangedObjects`
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSomeValue {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"key.path.involving.anNSArrayController.arrangedObjects"];
}

@end
```

How do I declare dependency between key paths in such cases? And, why is this whole thing happening?

(Yes, I know about `will/didChangeValueForKey:` and friends, but wrapping up every affecting key path with a(nother) setter is terrible and I'd like to avoid it.)

Comment: If you find why, please share ;) I am right now observing strange behavior for `KVO` with classes generated out of `Core Data` entities.

Comment: Have you tried using `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key` instead ?

Comment: The default implementation of `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` just searches `+keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` and returns its result -- overriding it makes no difference here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSController` and its subclasses are full of KVO "black magic" and unexpected behaviors. (For another example, they don't respect certain KVO options like `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior`) You will be disappointed if you expect them to behave like "normal" objects with respect to KVO. They exist primarily to support Cocoa bindings. Although at first glance bindings may look like mere syntactic sugar on top of KVO, you can see (by overriding the KVO supporting methods of a bound-to object and setting breakpoints in them) that there's actually quite a bit more going on underneath the covers than a simple KVO observation.

Please [file bugs with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) to increase the likelihood that they'll fix (or at least document) these sorts of issues/behavior.

Comment: **SIGH.** That would certainly explain why I just can't make properties depending on the `selectionIndexes` (or `selection`) of my `NSArrayController` properties work.. Very annoying - thanks for the info!

Comment: @ipmcc : do you happen to know whether the missing support for `NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior` (and the *New and *Old options too, btw) is documented somewhere? Because funnily, the Apple docs state "This object is fully key-value coding compliant"

Comment: @Mojo66 This, like much of Cocoa Bindings, doesn't appear to be documented. But trust me... ;)